# Criar Fibonacci em uma função linear com delegate

Tags: c#

Usando uma lista para o *Delegate*(aprendi que isso se chama função linear, é isso mesmo?) eu decremento a lista para ela ir pegando os respectivos valores, mas não consigo fazer uma operação aritmética simples com "X", pois eu tenho uma lista e "X" passa ser essa lista, conforme Omni e ramaral me explicaram nos posts abaixo.

A Fibonacci eu sei fazer, quero é fazê-la da forma citada.

Sei que Fibonacci é: `Fn = F(n-1) + F(n-2)`.
O `x - 1` e o `x - 2` dá erro.
Nesse caso o retorno da função seria uma lista(Fibonacci)

Veja como ficou meu método.

```
List<int> lista = new List<int>();

Func<List<int>, List<int>> calcFib = null;

for(int i = 0; i <= tamanho-1; i++)
    lista.Add(i);

calcFib = x => x.Count == 0 ? 0 : (x - 1 + x - 2) + calcFib(x.Take(x.Count - 1).ToList<int>());

return calcFib(lista);
```

A minha lista, é o limite da sequência que eu quero implementar o Fibonacci. No caso, a var `tamanho`. Se `tamanho for 10`, por exemplo, seria o resultado: `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34`

```
public List<int> novoFibonacci(int tamanho)
        {
            List<int> lista = new List<int>();

            Func<List<int>, List<int>> calcFib = null;

            for(int i = 0; i <= tamanho-1; i++)
                lista.Add(i);

            calcFib = x => x

            return calcFib(lista);
        }
```

Comment: O que é essa `lista`?

Comment: Perdão, é que eu copiei do post anterior meu. Vou editar e recolocar, assim explico melhor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve pegar em cada um dos valores da sua lista e calcular o valor correspondente na serie de Fibonacci

Seria algo assim:

```
public List<int> novoFibonacci(int tamanho)
{
    List<int> lista = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= tamanho - 1; i++)
    {
        lista.Add(i);
    }

    //O Select executa GetFibonacciAt() passando a ela cada um dos elementos da lista, 
    //returnado um IEnumerable<int> contendo cada um dos resultados.

    return lista.Select(n => GetFibonacciAt(n)).ToList();
}
```

Você tem de criar o método `int GetFibonacciAt(int n)` que calcule o valor correspondente a `n` na serie de Fibonacci.

Se quiser eu posto essa função.

**EDIT**

Solução com uma função em linha como pedido:

```
public List<int> novoFibonacci(int tamanho)
{
    Func<int, int> getFibonacciAt = 
               n => (n <= 1) ? n : getFibonacciAt(n - 1) + getFibonacciAt(n - 2);

    var lista = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= tamanho - 1; i++)
    {
        lista.Add(i);
    }
    return lista.Select(n => getFibonacciAt(n)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Deixa eu tentar primeiro. Se quebrar a cabeça e não consegui, aí te peço ajuda. Desde já, grato.

Comment: Pelo visto, será um método que retorne um Fib, tipo: Fn = (Fn-1 + Fn-2), exatamente o que eu tenho feito por aí, acho que é isso, certo?

Comment: fazer um método linear semelhante a esse não dá, certo?  qdr = square => square.Count == 0 ? 0 : square.Last() * square.Last() + qdr(square.Take(square.Count - 1).ToList<int>()); Esse aí eu faço a soma dos quadrados dos elementos em um array.  Era isso que eu gostaria de fazer, só que com Fibonacci.

Comment: Julgo que de forma linear não dá porque o próximo valor é calculado em função do anterior.

Comment: Entendi, era exatamente isso que eu buscava, entendimento. Isso tudo é um estudo que eu estou fazendo para ter maior domínio sobre determinados assuntos. O dia-a-dia de um programador é vivido em cima de decisões baseadas em certezas, em padrões já testados. É isso que eu estou fazendo. Obrigado.

Comment: Estive a pensar melhor no assunto e encontrei um modo de fazer isso em linha.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar duas funções em linha, ou somente uma mais complexa, uma para calcular o Fibonacci.

```
    //função 1 recursividade (usando duas funções em linha)
    Func<int, int> calcFib = null;
    calcFib = 
        x => 
        (x < 2) ? x : calcFib(x-1) + calcFib(x-2);
    Func<int, List<int>> Fibonacci =
        x => 
        Enumerable.Range(1, x).Select(s => calcFib(s)).ToList();


    //função 2 somente linq (usando apenas uma função em linha)
    Func<int, List<int>> Fibonacci2 =
        x => 
        Enumerable.Range(1, x).Select(
            a => 
            Enumerable.Range(1, a).Skip(2).Aggregate(
                new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 1), 
                (seq, index) => 
                new KeyValuePair<int, int>(seq.Value, seq.Key + seq.Value)
            ).Value
        ).ToList();
```

Exemplo no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FZR6cF)